# Using an angular directive stored in a variable in thymleaf

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, thymeleaf

I am working on an issue in an application that mixes angularjs and thymeleaf.  I want to build a template in thymeleaf that will allow me to use a variable to specify an angular attribute directive to use.

It seems like thymeleaf does not allow variables to be used as attributes.  I have tried the following:

```
<div th:attr="${portlet.attrDirective}">
     ....
</div>
```

Didn't work

```
<div th:inline="text">
     <div [[${portlet.attrDirective}]]>
         ...
     </div>
 </div>
```

Also didn't work

Am I doing something wrong?

There also is the possiblity of they `portlet.attrDirective` being `null`.

Comment: can you share some snapshots of web element inspector view?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working finally using the following code:

```
<div th:attr="${portlet.attrDirective == null} ? nodirective : ${portlet.attrDirective}=${portlet.attrDirective}">
    ...
</div>
```

Does anyone have a more readable solution?